# Cordova app has performance issues on heavy usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

We have built a cordova app, which collects data and sends them to a server system. Sadly its a quite old app without angular, ionic or something - just cordova and jQuery.

We also dont have any template engine, we switch pages by using `window.location = 'lipsum.html';`.

Everything was working fine for the last years but now we are facing some performance issues on heavy usage. **After opening about 50 to 100 pages the app is deadly slow and takes up to 20 seconds to change the page. Also memory and CPU are high.**

Has anybody experienced this before?

Used versions:

- Cordova: 5.4.1
- iOS: 9.2 (13C75)
- Hardware: iPod touch 5G